# which column does Z belong to?

Tags: letter-sequence

1----2

---

A----B
E----C
F----D
H----G
I----J
K----O
L----P
M----Q
N----R
T----S
V----U
W----
X----
Y----

Which column does Z belong to? Left(1) or right(2)?

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer is:

> Left(1), because all of the letters on the left side can be written without curves.